# How to move existing Indexes and primary keys to secondary filegroup in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, indexing, primary-key, filegroup

All the indexes and primary keys were created in primary file(.mdf).
Is there any way to move all the index and primary key to secondary filegroup(.ndf)??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Following query:

```
DECLARE @SchemaName NVARCHAR(300),
        @ObjectName NVARCHAR(300),
        @IndexName NVARCHAR(300),
        @Columns NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @IncludeColumns NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @Command NVARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE IndexCursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT SCHEMA_NAME(o.schema_id),OBJECT_NAME(o.object_id), i.name, 
            STUFF((SELECT ',['+c.name+']'
            FROM sys.index_columns ic 
            INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON c.column_id = ic.column_id AND c.object_id = ic.object_id
            WHERE ic.object_id = i.object_id
                AND ic.index_id = i.index_id
                AND ic.is_included_column=0 
            ORDER BY ic.key_ordinal
            FOR XML PATH('')
            ),1,1,'') IndexColumn,
            STUFF((SELECT ',['+c.name+']'
            FROM sys.index_columns ic 
            INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON c.column_id = ic.column_id AND c.object_id = ic.object_id
            WHERE ic.object_id = i.object_id
                AND ic.index_id = i.index_id
                AND ic.is_included_column=1
            ORDER BY ic.key_ordinal
            FOR XML PATH('')
            ),1,1,'') IncludeColumn,
            i.filter_definition
    FROM sys.indexes i
    INNER JOIN sys.objects o ON o.object_id = i.object_id
    INNER JOIN sys.data_spaces ds ON ds.data_space_id = i.data_space_id
    WHERE ds.name = 'PRIMARY'
        AND OBJECTPROPERTY(i.object_id,'IsUserTable')=1

OPEN IndexCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM IndexCursor INTO @SchemaName, @ObjectName, @IndexName, @Columns, @IncludeColumns
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0 BEGIN

    SET @Command = 'ALTER INDEX ' + @IndexName + ' ON [' + @SchemaName + '].['+@ObjectName+']('+@Columns+') '+ ISNULL('Include ('+@IncludeColumns+')','') + ' ON [YourFileGroupName]'
    EXEC(@Command)

    FETCH NEXT FROM IndexCursor INTO @SchemaName, @ObjectName, @IndexName, @Columns, @IncludeColumns
END
CLOSE IndexCursor
DEALLOCATE IndexCursor
```

Comment: How do i move all my constraints(PK & FK) along with indexes to secondary filegroup?

Comment: @Pradeep. You must change select query and use of `sys.sysconstraints` system table instead of `sys.Indexes`.

Answer (score 0):

1. You cannot move indexes created using a UNIQUE or PRIMARY KEY constraint using Management Studio. To move these indexes use the CREATE INDEX statement with the (DROP_EXISTING=ON) option in Transact-SQL.
2. If a table has a clustered index, moving the clustered index to a new filegroup moves the table to that filegroup.

For step by step instuctions you can use [MS documentation.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175905.aspx)